# download attribute not downloading with custom name

Tags: html

Here is an example link:

```
<a class="imglink" download="0232479.png" href="https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=200x200&cht=qr&chl=0232479" title="0232479">0232479</a>
```

[LINK](https://chart.googleapis.com/chart?chs=200x200&cht=qr&chl=0232479.png)

Answer (score 0):

According to the mozilla dev docs for the `download` attribute on the `a` tag;

> • This attribute only works for same-origin URLs.
>
> • If the HTTP header `Content-Disposition:` gives a different filename than this attribute, the HTTP header takes priority over this attribute.

So the `download` tag will not work for `chart.googleapis.com` as your site is not on that domain.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-download

Comment: For OP: So if you want this to work you'll need to proxy it through your own domain with some server-side script.